# How to draw a strike and dip on a geologic map?

Tags: homework

[image]

I know that Strike and dip refer to the orientation or attitude of a geologic feature. The strike line of a bed, fault, or other planar feature, is a line representing the intersection of that feature with a horizontal plane. On a geologic map, this is represented with a short straight line segment oriented parallel to the strike line. 
The dip gives the steepest angle of descent of a tilted bed or feature relative to a horizontal plane, and is given by the number (0°-90°) as well as a letter (N,S,E,W) with rough direction in which the bed is dipping downwards. 
However, I am completely clueless about how to solve it on a geologic map as in the example given above

Comment: Please tag as homework if that is the case.

Comment: As you note, strike is a line representing the intersection of a feature with the horizontal plane. Your map shows where the contact outcrops at the surface and the topographic elevation contours. Can you find two points on the contact that are at the same elevation? If you draw a line between those two points, is the elevation the same everywhere along that line? How would the direction of that line relate to the strike?

Comment: Dip is perpendicular to the strike so if you can draw strike lines at 2 different elevations and draw a perpendicular between them, you can measure the rise over the horizontal distance between the lines. Use trigonometry to calculate dip angle